# problem with UIWebview

Tags: iphone

i have a problem like this :

```
UIViewontrollerA.m

 {
-(IBAction)loadMySite {

    MySiteViewController *controller = [[MySiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySiteViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];

 }
```

and in my MySiteviewController.m i have this in my viewWillAppear :

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.mySite.fr"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

    [self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
    self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

}
```

but i takes a long time to load the web site ?

is there an other solution to do this ?? thanks four your answers

Comment: Does it take longer than the same site in Safari (after clearing the cache)?

Comment: i have not try it in safari. how to do this please ?

Comment: No, i am sorry. yes it take less than in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but that is as fast as you can load a web page in a `UIWebView`. Your only alternatives would be to:

- Make the server faster.
- Make the data served by she server smaller.
- Bundle the data in your app.

As an alternative to bundle data in your app, you could bundle a set of static data that is initially loaded fast, and then request the actual data from the real server. This could give the user an illusion of faster load time.